# Find the Sum of Squares and using them complete an F-test for goodness of fit

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, anova, sums-of-squares, f-statistic

I have this question ( would be grateful if someone could put it on for me)

https://gyazo.com/5afe5d7c9d12acdff8f9c55db74f97c9

[image]

And I am concerned with part b).

I know what $RSS = SSE$ is due to the question, but surely from the data I have

$$SST = \sum_i (y_i - \bar y)^2$$

$$SST = SSR + SSE$$

I know that I want to find $$F = \frac{SSR/(p-1)}{SSE/(n-p)}$$ and that $n=21$ and $p=2$

Could someone just point me in the right direction please

**Edit:** I realise that I am given the SST for each group rather than the total SST. So I was wondering if there is a quicker way to find the total SST from each group SST.

Clearly the cumbersome way to do this would find what $\sum_i y_i^2 -n\bar y^2$ is for all values of $y$. But seeing as there are 21 values this will take some time.

Comment: (1) Please quote enough of the question so that we can understand your post.  (2) What does the title (about the inverse cumulative F distribution) have to do with the contents of your post (which focuses on sums of squares)?  They seem completely different.

Comment: @whuber (1) The question is contained in the gyazo link. It has a table which will take a lot of time to put into this. I do not have a high enough reputation to be able to include images in my posts. (2) The question asks to complete a F-test for goodness of fit. I know how to do that, but the problem is to do with the Computation of the sum of squares. Once I have the sum of squares I can then go on to do the F test. I will reword the title if it is better

Comment: Seems like I do have enough rep. My mistake. just on other forums it says I cant post images due to not having enough rep